# Why does the type hint of a set type variable make the ` mypy ` module not recognize the attributes of a namedtuple in this set type variable?

Tags: python

I have a question about the `mypy` module. It is demonstrated in the code below:

```
from typing import Set, NamedTuple
from collections import namedtuple

Student = namedtuple('Student', 'name english math')
students: Set[NamedTuple] = {Student('John', 100, 80),
                             Student('Mary', 90, 90),}
for student in students:
  print(student.name)
```

When I used the `mypy` module to check the snippet of code, it reported the following error for the last line:

```
test.py:8: error: "NamedTuple" has no attribute "name"  [attr-defined]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I also found that this error was not reported after I omitted the type hint for the variable `students` in line 4 as follows:

```
from typing import Set, NamedTuple
from collections import namedtuple

Student = namedtuple('Student', 'name english math')
students = {Student('John', 100, 80),
            Student('Mary', 90, 90),}
for student in students:
  print(student.name)
```

Can anyone kindly tell me why this error occurs? And what is the appropriate way to let the `mypy` module know the attributes of the namedtuple `Student` without omitting the type hint for the variable `students` in a situation like this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to annotate `students` as a set of `Student`s (which you've defined as having a `name` attribute), not the base `NamedTuple` type (which isn't specifically associated with your `Student` namedtuple):

```
from typing import Set
from collections import namedtuple

Student = namedtuple('Student', 'name english math')
students: Set[Student] = {Student('John', 100, 80),
                             Student('Mary', 90, 90),}
for student in students:
    print(student.name)
```

If you want to use `typing.NamedTuple`, you use it as the base class for your specific namedtuple type:

```
from typing import NamedTuple, Set

class Student(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    english: int
    math: int
    
students: Set[Student] = {Student('John', 100, 80),
                             Student('Mary', 90, 90),}
for student in students:
    print(student.name)
```

Note that the `typing.NamedTuple` version has type annotations for the individual attributes; the `collections.namedtuple` version implicitly types them all as `Any`.